# Firewalld Blocking SSH between Clients on WireGuard LAN

Tags: debian, firewalld, wireguard

What needs to be allowed in firewalld so that WireGuard clients can connect to each other via SSH?

---

### The Setup

I have two clients and a server on a WireGuard VPN network. All of them are running Debian 11.

```
CLIENT A -------- SERVER -------- CLIENT B
10.0.1.2         10.0.1.1         10.0.1.3
```

---

### What Can Be Done

- I can SSH from either client to the server.
- I can SSH from the server to either client.

**Problem:** *But when I try to SSH client to client, I get, "ssh: connect to host 10.0.1.2 port 22: No route to host"*

---

### Troubleshooting

1. The path between the machines is up because I can ping...

   - client to server,
   - server to client,
   - and client to client.
2. The ports are accessible because I can telnet...

   - from the server to either client on port 22.
   - from either client to the server on port 22.

**Problem:** *But when I try to telnet client to client, I get "telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host"*

---

### What Has Been Confirmed

- SSH is a listed service on firewalld: `firewall-cmd --list-services` returns `ssh`
- ip-foward is set on the kernel: `sysctl -a` returns `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`
- Forwarding is set on the iptables: `iptables-save` returns `-A FORWARD -i wg0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT`
- Disabling firewalld on the server DOES allow an SSH connection between the two WireGuard clients.

Thanks for your help and pointers.

Comment: Show us `ip route show` output from the clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While firewalld is generally an excellent tool for configuring the firewall on a Linux box, for this particular use case -- forwarding traffic for other hosts -- it's kind of a pain in the neck to use. I would suggest turning it off on your server, and just using iptables (or nftables) directly.

If you really want to use firewalld, however, try this (as root):

###### 1. Create a custom zone for your WireGuard interface that accepts all traffic:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --new-zone=mywg
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=mywg --set-target=ACCEPT
firewall-cmd --reload
```

###### 2. Add "rich" rules to the zone to reject inbound connections from WireGuard to the server itself:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=mywg --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" priority="30001" protocol value="tcp" reject'
firewall-cmd --zone=mywg --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" priority="30002" protocol value="udp" reject'
firewall-cmd --zone=mywg --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv6" priority="30003" protocol value="tcp" reject'
firewall-cmd --zone=mywg --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv6" priority="30004" protocol value="udp" reject'
```

###### 3. Add "direct" rules to allow forwarding of IPv4 SSH connections between other WireGuard hosts, and reject everything else:

```
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -i wg0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 1 -i wg0 -o wg0 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 2 -i wg0 -j REJECT
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv6 filter FORWARD 0 -i wg0 -j REJECT
```

###### 4. Bind the zone to your WireGuard interface and save your changes:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=mywg --add-interface=wg0
firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent
```

You can add more IPv4 direct rules between 0 and 2 (renumbering the `REJECT` rule to be last) if you want to allow other types of traffic between your WireGuard hosts (or just replace rules 0 and 1 with a single rule like `-i wg0 -o wg0 -J ACCEPT` if you want to allow the server to forward any and all traffic between your WireGuard hosts).

See Hub and Spoke section of this [How to Use WireGuard With Firewalld](https://www.procustodibus.com/blog/2021/07/wireguard-firewalld/#firewalld-configuration-on-host-c) article for a full explanation (Host C is your server in this article).

Comment: Thanks for your help @JustinLudwig